# Can params be used to call methods with strongly typed parameters?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a method that calls a delegate based on the state of the network. The method must decide where to call the method( server, client ). In order for this to work with any method, I've defined the following delegate:

```
public delegate void NetworkCall( params object[] args );
```

This will take any parameter, but will only work with methods with the exact same signature. This results in this stuff:

```
protected virtual void DoNetowrkMove( params object[] args )
{
    destination = ( Vector3 )args[0];
}
```

Which is not an ideal solution. Would it be possible to "unpack" the objects in 'args' into a more typesafe method call? For example:

```
protected virtual void DoNetowrkMove( Vector3 newDestination )
{
    destination = newDestination;
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you change your delegate declaration.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek And that will work with any method?

Comment: Any method that takes the same set of parameters and returns the same type. I really don't get why you need a delegate that matches everything. Are you sure you're not facing XY problem here?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Any method needs to be called. The method is just passed on to see how it should be called. I'm using trying to avoid duplicating this code for every unique call I make to something that should be networked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure completely grasp the use-case here. It seems like a more flexible solution would involve some true serialization/deserialization for the data being sent, which would allow a type-safe communications end-to-end.

That said, while delegates don't allow what you're trying to do directly, you can create a generic method to automate most of the work:

```
delegate void Callback(params object[] args);

static void Method1(params string[] args) { }

static Callback Wrap<T>(Action<T[]> action)
{
    return (Callback)((object[] args) => action(args.Cast<T>().ToArray()));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Callback callback1 = Wrap<string>(Method1);
}
```

This will cast each element of the `args` array to the type specified. Of course, this requires that the wrapped method has an array for its sole parameter, e.g. a `params` array. To handle something more like your specific example, you could do this:

```
static void Method2(string arg) { }

static Callback Wrap<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    return (Callback)((object[] args) => action((T)args[0]));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Callback callback2 = Wrap<string>(Method2);
}
```

As with the .NET generic delegate types `Action` and `Func`, you would have to declare a specific wrapper method for each parameter-count delegate. The above would work for just one parameter. If you have examples of two parameters, then you'd need to add:

```
static void Method3(string arg1, bool arg2) { }

static Callback Wrap<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action)
{
    return (Callback)((object[] args) => action((T1)args[0], (T2)args[1]));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Callback callback3 = Wrap<string, bool>(Method3);
}
```

And so on. Whether it's actually worth it to write these little wrappers would of course depend on how much you'd use them. I'd say after the third or fourth callback, you'd probably find it worthwhile.

Of course, I'm still thinking you might be better off with a serialization-based approach instead. But that's a different question. :)

Comment: This is a good solution. I settled with just taking a parameterless , void returning method, and relying on the caller to call the method inside of that. With this, I could either call a method like that locally, or call a method over the network( this is delegated to a 3rd party, Unity3D ) which deals with params object[] anyway. It ( presumably ) uses reflection. Your solution is a little more tedious, but certainly safer and better, and I'll probably switch to this. Thanks!